# C string to int without any libraries

Tags: c, casting, kernel

I'm trying to write my first kernel module so I'm not able to include libraries for atoi, strtol, etc. How can I convert a string to int without these built-in functions? I tried:

```
int num;
num = string[0] - '0';
```

which works for the first character, but if I remove the `[0]` to try and convert the full string it gives me a warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast. So what do I do?

Comment: What kernel are you writing a module for, that has no standard library functions like these? Also, if you haven't the slightest idea of the machanics behind converting a string to an integer (hint: it's not as simple as a cast), you should absolutely spend some more time learning before embarking on a kernel journey.

Comment: I don't have a choice. It's for an embedded systems course, but even though I supposedly have the 1 programming pre-req I'm way behind in my programming capabilities. It's an arm-linux qemu virtual machine. It has busybox, but that's about it. Hmm I was told I couldn't include stdlib or stdio.

Comment: Also, there are many open-source implementations of the C standard library, including functions like `atoi`. I suggest you have a thorough look at one of them.

Comment: The Linux kernel has all of the standard library functions like these you will need to link directly against. Look through the kernel sources.

Comment: After clarifying that this is for a Linux kernel module, I've closed this question as a duplicate. If it does not answer your question, please add a comment.

Comment: what do you think `string - '0'` will do?

Comment: It subtracts the difference between ascii chars I guess so that explains why it doesn't work with strings. What I was looking for turned out to be simple_strtoul()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your own string to int function, make sure you check and protect against overflow. For example:

```
/* an atoi replacement performing the conversion in a single
   pass and incorporating 'err' to indicate a failed conversion.
   passing NULL as error causes it to be ignored */
int strtoi (const char *s, unsigned char *err)
{
    char *p = (char *)s;
    int nmax = (1ULL << 31) - 1;    /* INT_MAX  */
    int nmin = -nmax - 1;           /* INT_MIN  */
    long long sum = 0;
    char sign = *p;

    if (*p == '-' || *p == '+') p++;

    while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
        sum = sum * 10 - (*p - '0');
        if (sum < nmin || (sign != '-' && -sum > nmax)) goto error;
        p++;
    }

    if (sign != '-') sum = -sum;

    return (int)sum;

error:

    fprintf (stderr, "strtoi() error: invalid conversion for type int.\n");
    if (err) *err = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the sign is ***not*** `'-'`, then you reverse the sign on the sum?  That seems completely backwards.  (`if (sign != '-') sum = -sum;`)

Comment: Yes, it will make you work, but to do it in one pass, starting at the *beginning* of the string, you are working with a *negative* `sum`. Notice how `sum` is initialized to `0` and your first conversion `sum = sum * 10 - (*p - '0');` will result in `sum` being *negative*. Work through it slowly, you'll see. Make it easy on yourself, do a manual trip through the function for say `'5'`, then say `'51'` it is a pretty slick way to approach the conversion. The alternative is to add code to find the end of the string and work backwards -- that just makes it less efficient.

Comment: Interesting technique.   Also, on my tool-set, I got a compiler warning "possible loss of data" when trying to `return sum;` (a `long long`), when the function returns `int`;  See my answer below, which also does it in one-pass (but without the INT_MIN/INT_MAX limits or the error indicator)

Comment: The `long long` is used to force an intermediate conversion using 64-bit so that *overflow* testing and protection can be implemented. You are guaranteed to return only values within the valid range of `int`. Try the conversion with `2147483647` and then `2147483648` (one over the `int` range). If the intermediate calculation exceeds the range of `int` an error is generated and `0` is returned. To remove the warning just `return (int)sum;` I should probably add that anyway.

Comment: "make sure you check and protect against overflow" -->  `nmax + 1` looks like `int` overflow (UB) to me.  Recommend `-nmax - 1`

Comment: The compiler must be smarter than I am and distribute the `-` sign, because even with `-pedantic` it raised no concern over the storage of `nmin` or the intermediate result `(nmax + 1)`. I see and will manually distribute the `-` sign, but I would like to know from a compiler standpoint how an intermediate computation like that is handled, and why when there is a technical overflow of an intermediate value where the final result is within range, no warning is raised.

Comment: How is that handled? --> `Int` overflow is UB, whatever way compiler wants.  A warning/diagnostic is not required.

Comment: Yes, I get that. I guess what I was curious about is how the intermediate calculations is done, because while we may look at it and say `int x = -(2147483647 + 1);` invokes UB in `(2147483647 + 1)` before the `-` is applied, the computation in `gcc` is obviously handled with an intermediate type sufficient to prevent overflow and produces the proper response. If overflow actually occurred, the result before the `-` is distributed would be negative resulting in an incorrect value. That does not occur (in over 1,000,000 successive computations). How does that not occur?

Comment: @chux I'm not sure there was overflow to begin with in `-(nmax + 1)` compared to `-nmax - 1`. Under 6.3.1.1(2) any value in excess `2147483647` causes *integer promotion* to take place from `int` to `unsigned int`. However, the result of the computation can be represented by an `int`, so the result is *signed* and not *implementation-defined* and therefore no *implementation-defined* signal would be raised under 6.3.1.3.

Comment: "any value in excess 2147483647 causes integer promotion" does not apply with the `+` operation `nmax + 1`.  Both `nmax` and `1` are in the `int` (32-bit) range. "integer promotion" applies to the argument individually.   No integer promotion occurs before or after the addition.  Yet since the result of  `nmax + 1` is outside the range of `int`, it is `int` overflow and thus UB.  The rest of the computation is irrelevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104487/discussion-between-chux-and-david-c-rankin).

Comment: I did have one note to add to our discussion regarding the application of *integer promotion*, it does apply as part of the usual arithmetic conversions. § 6.3.1.1 (note 58).

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the [0]. That means that you are subtracting '0' from the pointer `string`, which is meaningless. You still need to dereference it:
`num = string[i] - '0';`

Comment: Is there some way to for-loop through this?

Comment: @Austin You convert it one digit at a time, and you combine the digits somehow (hint: `* 10` once per digit).

Comment: This is not really an answer. This should have been placed as a comment

Answer (score 0):

This function skips leading and trailing whitespace, handles one optional `+` / `-` sign, and returns 0 on invalid input,

```
// Convert standard null-terminated string to an integer
// - Skips leading whitespaces.
// - Skips trailing whitespaces.
// - Allows for one, optional +/- sign at the front.
// - Returns zero if any non-+/-, non-numeric, non-space character is encountered.
// - Returns zero if digits are separated by spaces (eg "123  45")
// - Range is checked against Overflow/Underflow (INT_MAX / INT_MIN), and returns 0.
int StrToInt(const char* s)
{
    int minInt = 1 << (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1);
    int maxInt = -(minInt+1);
    char* w;

    do { // Skip any leading whitespace
        for(w=" \t\n\v\f\r"; *w && *s != *w; ++w) ;
        if (*s == *w) ++s; else break;
    } while(*s);

    int sign = 1;
    if ('-' == *s) sign = -1; 
    if ('+' == *s || '-' == *s) ++s;

    long long i=0;
    while('0' <= *s && *s <= '9')
    {
        i = 10*i + *s++ - '0';
        if (sign*i < minInt || maxInt < sign*i)
        {
            i = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    while (*s) // Skip any trailing whitespace
    {
        for(w=" \t\n\v\f\r"; *w && *s != *w; ++w) ;
        if (*w && *s == *w) ++s; else break;
    }

    return (int)(!*s*sign*i);
}
```

Comment: Based on the answer by @DavidCRankin, I updated my answer so that it now respects limits of Integer, and returns 0 in case of overflow/underflow.

Answer (score 0):

1. A string is an `array` of characters, represented by an address (a.k.a `pointer`).
2. An `pointer` has an value that might look something like `0xa1de2bdf`. This value tells me where the start of the array is.
3. You cannot subtract a `pointer` type with a `character` type (e.g 0xa1de2bdf - 'b' does not really make sense).

To convert a string to a number, you could try this:

```
//Find the length of the string
int len = 0;
while (str[len] != '\0') { 
   len++;
}

//Loop through the string
int num = 0, i = 0, digit;
for (i=0; i<len; i++) {

   //Extract the digit
   digit = ing[i] - '0';

   //Multiply the digit with its correct position (ones, tens, hundreds, etc.)
   num += digit * pow(10, (len-1)-i);
}
```

Of course if you are not allowed to use `math.h` library, you could write your own `pow(a,b)` function which gives you the value of `a^b`.

```
int mypowfunc(int a, int b) {
   int i=0, ans=1;
   //multiply the value a for b number of times
   for (i=0; i<b; i++) {
      ans *= a;
   }   
   return ans;
}
```

I have written the code above in a way that is simple to understand. It assumes that your string has a null character ('\0') right behind the last useful character (which is good practice).

Also, you might want to check that the string is actually a valid string with only digits (e.g '0', '1', '2', etc.). You could do this by including an `if... else..` statement while looping through the string.

Answer (score 0):

In modern kernels you want to use `kstrto*`:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L274

```
274 /**
275  * kstrtoul - convert a string to an unsigned long
276  * @s: The start of the string. The string must be null-terminated, and may also
277  *  include a single newline before its terminating null. The first character
278  *  may also be a plus sign, but not a minus sign.
279  * @base: The number base to use. The maximum supported base is 16. If base is
280  *  given as 0, then the base of the string is automatically detected with the
281  *  conventional semantics - If it begins with 0x the number will be parsed as a
282  *  hexadecimal (case insensitive), if it otherwise begins with 0, it will be
283  *  parsed as an octal number. Otherwise it will be parsed as a decimal.
284  * @res: Where to write the result of the conversion on success.
285  *
286  * Returns 0 on success, -ERANGE on overflow and -EINVAL on parsing error.
287  * Used as a replacement for the obsolete simple_strtoull. Return code must
288  * be checked.
289 */
```

Answer (score 0):

" not able to include libraries" --> Unclear if code is allowed access to `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN`.  There is *no way* to determine the minimum/maximum signed integer in a completely portable fashion without using the language provided macros like `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN`.

Use `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN` is available.  Else we could *guess* the `char` width is 8.  We could guess there are no padding bits. We could guess that integers are 2's complement.  With these reasonable *assumptions*, minimum and maximum are defined below.

Note: Shifting into the sign bit is *undefined behavior* (UB), so don't do that.

---

Let us add another restriction: make a solution that works for any signed integer from `signed char` to `intmax_t`.  This disallows code from using a wider type, as there may not be a wider type.

---

```
typedef int Austin_int;

#define Austin_INT_MAXMID ( ((Austin_int)1) << (sizeof(Austin_int)*8 - 2) )
#define Austin_INT_MAX (Austin_INT_MAXMID - 1 + Austin_INT_MAXMID)
#define Austin_INT_MIN (-Austin_INT_MAX - 1)

int Austin_isspace(int ch) {
  const char *ws = " \t\n\r\f\v";
  while (*ws) {
    if (*ws == ch) return 1;
    ws++;
  }
  return 0;
}

// *endptr points to where parsing stopped
// *errorptr indicates overflow
Austin_int Austin_strtoi(const char *s, char **endptr, int *errorptr) {
  int error = 0;
  while (Austin_isspace(*s)) {
    s++;
  }

  char sign = *s;
  if (*s == '-' || *s == '+') {
    s++;
  }

  Austin_int sum = 0;
  while (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9') {
    int ch = *s - '0';
    if (sum <= Austin_INT_MIN / 10 &&
        (sum < Austin_INT_MIN / 10 || -ch < Austin_INT_MIN % 10)) {
      sum = Austin_INT_MIN;
      error = 1;
    } else {
      sum = sum * 10 - ch;
    }
    s++;
  }

  if (sign != '-') {
    if (sum < -Austin_INT_MAX) {
      sum = Austin_INT_MAX;
      error = 1;
    } else {
      sum = -sum;
    }
  }

  if (endptr) {
    *endptr = (char *) s;
  }
  if (errorptr) {
    *errorptr = error;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The above depends on C99 or later in the `Austin_INT_MIN  Austin_INT_MIN % 10` part.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest and safest way I could come up with

```
int str_to_int(const char * str, size_t n, int * int_value) {
    int i;
    int cvalue;
    int value_muliplier = 1;
    int res_value = 0;
    int neg = 1; // -1 for negative and 1 for whole.
    size_t str_len; // String length.
    int end_at = 0; // Where loop should end.

    if (str == NULL || int_value == NULL || n <= 0)
        return -1;

    // Get string length
    str_len = strnlen(str, n);

    if (str_len <= 0)
        return -1;

    // Is negative.
    if (str[0] == '-') {
        neg = -1;
        end_at = 1; // If negative 0 item in 'str' is skipped.
    }

    // Do the math.
    for (i = str_len - 1; i >= end_at; i--) {
        cvalue = char_to_int(str[i]);

        // Character not a number.
        if (cvalue == -1)
            return -1;

        // Do the same math that is down below.
        res_value += cvalue * value_muliplier;
        value_muliplier *= 10;
    }

    /*
     * "436"
     * res_value = (6 * 1) + (3 * 10) + (4 * 100)
    */

    *int_value = (res_value * neg);
    return 0;
}

int char_to_int(char c) {
    int cvalue = (int)c;

    // Not a number.
    // 48 to 57 is 0 to 9 in ascii.
    if (cvalue < 48 || cvalue > 57)
        return -1;

    return cvalue - 48; // 48 is the value of zero in ascii.
}
```